# Convert Stata code to R code "Convert numbers into words"

Tags: r, stata, converters

I want to convert this code from Stata to R in order to convert numbers into words or maybe I can do the same but using R commands. I don't know anything about programming in Stata.

I really hope someone can help me, please.
THANK YOU!

```
**** Convertidor de Números en Letras
local nums N21 N22 N23
local lets l21 l22 l23
local N: word count `nums'
forvalues n=1/`N'{
    local t: word `n' of  `lets'
    local z: word `n' of `nums'
        
g `t'=string(`z')
replace `t'=subinstr(`t',"0","CERO",.) if `z'==0
replace `t'=string(floor(`z'/10)*10)+" Y "+string(mod(`z',10)) if inrange(`z',30,99)

local letters `" "30" "40" "50" "60" "70" "80" "90" "100" "29" "28" "27" "26" "25" "24" "23" "22" "21" "20" "19" "18" "17" "16" "15" "14" "13" "12" "11" "10" "9" "8" "7" "6" "5" "4" "3" "2" "1" "Y 0" "'
local values `" "TREINTA" "CUARENTA" "CINCUENTA" "SESENTA" "SETENTA" "OCHENTA" "NOVENTA" "CIEN" "VEINTINUEVE" "VEINTIOCHO" "VEINTISIETE" "VEINTISEIS" "VEINTICINCO" "VEINTICUATRO" "VEINTITRES" "VEINTIDOS" "VEINTIUNO" "VEINTE" "DIECINUEVE" "DIECIOCHO" "DIECISIETE" "DIECISEIS" "QUINCE" "CATORCE" "TRECE" "DOCE" "ONCE" "DIEZ" "NUEVE" "OCHO" "SIETE" "SEIS" "CINCO" "CUATRO" "TRES" "DOS" "UNO" "" "'
local N: word count `letters'
forvalues i=1/`N' {
        local l : word `i' of `letters'
        local x: word `i' of `values'
        replace `t'=subinstr(`t',"`l'","`x'",.) if inrange(`z',1,100)
}
    *** 101 a 1,000
replace `t'=string(floor(`z'/100)*100)+" "+ string(mod(floor(`z'/10)*10,100))+" Y "+string(mod(mod(`z',100),10)) if inrange(`z',101,1000)
replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," 0 Y 0"," ",.)
replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," 0 Y "," ",.)
replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," Y 0"," ",.)

local letters `" "1000" "100" "200" "300" "400" "500" "600" "700" "800" "900" "30" "40" "50" "60" "70" "80" "90"  "20 Y 9" "20 Y 8" "20 Y 7" "20 Y 6" "20 Y 5" "20 Y 4" "20 Y 3" "20 Y 2" "20 Y 1" "20" "10 Y 9" "10 Y 8" "10 Y 7" "10 Y 6" "10 Y 5" "10 Y 4" "10 Y 3" "10 Y 2" "10 Y 1" "10" "9" "8" "7" "6" "5" "4" "3" "2" "1" "'
local values `" "MIL" "CIENTO" "DOSCIENTOS" "TRESCIENTOS" "CUATROCIENTOS" "QUINIENTOS" "SEISCIENTOS" "SETECIENTOS" "OCHOCIENTOS" "NOVECIENTOS""TREINTA" "CUARENTA" "CINCUENTA" "SESENTA" "SETENTA" "OCHENTA" "NOVENTA" "VEINTINUEVE" "VEINTIOCHO" "VEINTISIETE" "VEINTISEIS" "VEINTICINCO" "VEINTICUATRO" "VEINTITRES" "VEINTIDOS" "VEINTIUNO" "VEINTE" "DIECINUEVE" "DIECIOCHO" "DIECISIETE" "DIECISEIS" "QUINCE" "CATORCE" "TRECE" "DOCE" "ONCE" "DIEZ" "NUEVE" "OCHO" "SIETE" "SEIS" "CINCO" "CUATRO" "TRES" "DOS" "UNO" "'
local N: word count `letters'
forvalues i=1/`N' {
        local l : word `i' of `letters'
        local x: word `i' of `values'
        replace `t'=subinstr(`t',"`l'","`x'",.) if inrange(`z',101,1000)
}
    ***1,001 a 1,999
replace `t'=substr(string(`z'),1,1)+"000"+" "+substr(string(`z'),2,1)+"00"+" "+substr(string(`z'),3,1)+"0"+" Y "+substr(string(`z'),4,1) if inrange(`z',1001,1999)
replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," 000 "," ",.) if inrange(`z',1001,1999)
replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," 00 Y "," ",.) if inrange(`z',1001,1999)
replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," 00 "," ",.) if inrange(`z',1001,1999)
replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," Y 0"," ",.) if inrange(`z',1001,1999)


local letters `" "1000" "100 0" "100" "200" "300" "400" "500" "600" "700" "800" "900" "30" "40" "50" "60" "70" "80" "90"  "20 Y 9" "20 Y 8" "20 Y 7" "20 Y 6" "20 Y 5" "20 Y 4" "20 Y 3" "20 Y 2" "20 Y 1" "20" "10 Y 9" "10 Y 8" "10 Y 7" "10 Y 6" "10 Y 5" "10 Y 4" "10 Y 3" "10 Y 2" "10 Y 1" "10" "9" "8" "7" "6" "5" "4" "3" "2" "1" "'
local values `" "MIL" "CIEN" "CIENTO" "DOSCIENTOS" "TRESCIENTOS" "CUATROCIENTOS" "QUINIENTOS" "SEISCIENTOS" "SETECIENTOS" "OCHOCIENTOS" "NOVECIENTOS""TREINTA" "CUARENTA" "CINCUENTA" "SESENTA" "SETENTA" "OCHENTA" "NOVENTA" "VEINTINUEVE" "VEINTIOCHO" "VEINTISIETE" "VEINTISEIS" "VEINTICINCO" "VEINTICUATRO" "VEINTITRES" "VEINTIDOS" "VEINTIUNO" "VEINTE" "DIECINUEVE" "DIECIOCHO" "DIECISIETE" "DIECISEIS" "QUINCE" "CATORCE" "TRECE" "DOCE" "ONCE" "DIEZ" "NUEVE" "OCHO" "SIETE" "SEIS" "CINCO" "CUATRO" "TRES" "DOS" "UNO" "'
local N: word count `letters'
forvalues i=1/`N' {
        local l : word `i' of `letters'
        local x: word `i' of `values'
        replace `t'=subinstr(`t',"`l'","`x'",.) if inrange(`z',1001,1999)
}
replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," 0"," ",.) if inrange(`z',1001,1999)
    ***2,000 a 999,999
replace `t'=substr(string(`z'),1,1)+" MIL "+substr(string(`z'),2,1)+"00"+" "+substr(string(`z'),3,1)+"0"+" Y "+substr(string(`z'),4,1) if inrange(`z',2000,9999)
replace `t'=substr(string(`z'),1,1)+"0 Y "+substr(string(`z'),2,1)+" MIL "+substr(string(`z'),3,1)+"00"+" "+substr(string(`z'),4,1)+"0"+" Y "+substr(string(`z'),5,1) if strlen(string(`z'))==5
replace `t'=substr(string(`z'),1,1)+"00 "+substr(string(`z'),2,1)+"0 Y "+substr(string(`z'),3,1)+" MIL "+substr(string(`z'),4,1)+"00"+" "+substr(string(`z'),5,1)+"0"+" Y "+substr(string(`z'),6,1) if strlen(string(`z'))==6

replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," 000 "," ",.) if inrange(`z',2000,999999)
replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," 00 Y "," ",.) if inrange(`z',2000,999999)
replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," 00 "," ",.) if inrange(`z',2000,999999)
replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," Y 0"," ",.) if inrange(`z',2000,999999)

local letters `" "1000" "100 0" "100" "200" "300" "400" "500" "600" "700" "800" "900" "30" "40" "50" "60" "70" "80" "90"  "20 Y 9" "20 Y 8" "20 Y 7" "20 Y 6" "20 Y 5" "20 Y 4" "20 Y 3" "20 Y 2" "20 Y 1" "20" "10 Y 9" "10 Y 8" "10 Y 7" "10 Y 6" "10 Y 5" "10 Y 4" "10 Y 3" "10 Y 2" "10 Y 1" "10" "9" "8" "7" "6" "5" "4" "3" "2" "1" "'
local values `" "MIL" "CIEN" "CIENTO" "DOSCIENTOS" "TRESCIENTOS" "CUATROCIENTOS" "QUINIENTOS" "SEISCIENTOS" "SETECIENTOS" "OCHOCIENTOS" "NOVECIENTOS""TREINTA" "CUARENTA" "CINCUENTA" "SESENTA" "SETENTA" "OCHENTA" "NOVENTA" "VEINTINUEVE" "VEINTIOCHO" "VEINTISIETE" "VEINTISEIS" "VEINTICINCO" "VEINTICUATRO" "VEINTITRES" "VEINTIDOS" "VEINTIUNO" "VEINTE" "DIECINUEVE" "DIECIOCHO" "DIECISIETE" "DIECISEIS" "QUINCE" "CATORCE" "TRECE" "DOCE" "ONCE" "DIEZ" "NUEVE" "OCHO" "SIETE" "SEIS" "CINCO" "CUATRO" "TRES" "DOS" "UNO" "'
local N: word count `letters'
forvalues i=1/`N' {
        local l : word `i' of `letters'
        local x: word `i' of `values'
        replace `t'=subinstr(`t',"`l'","`x'",.) if inrange(`z',2000,999999)
}
replace `t'=subinstr(`t'," 0"," ",.) if inrange(`z',2000,999999)

replace `t'=strtrim(itrim(`t'))
}
replace rz21=subinstr(rz21,string(N21),l21,.)
replace rz22=subinstr(rz22,string(N22),l22,.)
replace rz23=subinstr(rz23,string(N23),l23,.)
drop N21 N22 N23 l21 l22 l23
        ****************************
```

I tried to use a R function in spanish (i need it in this language) to do this but it just works from  1-1000 and I need to do this for numbers>1000. OR maybe an English function and then a translate function.
THANK YOU!!!

Comment: is this an exercise to translate code or you just need the functionality? https://github.com/ateucher/useful_code/blob/master/R/numbers2words.r

Comment: Thank you for interesting in my question! I wanted to translate that stata code into R code because I don't know how to read stata codes so I'm having troubles to do what i want to do. I already can convert numbers to words with your page that you share, thank you. Now, I just need to translate the result from english to spanish.

Comment: I'm sure you really, really need this, but as written it's a request for someone to write (translate) the code for you. That's not what StackOverflow is for ... You said (1) you have a Spanish function that works from 1-1000 and (2) you suggested that you know how to program in R; I assume you speak Spanish or can pick out the names of the numbers from the Stata code.  Maybe you could show us the existing R code and show what progress/say what ideas you've had so far about extending it? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: For me, "write R code to convert numbers to Spanish names" is an easier problem than "translate some Stata code to R" ...

Comment: Ben Bolker thank you for your coments, I'm modifying some things in the code that rawr sent me so that it remains with the structure of the Spanish language. Any error that I have and that I cannot solve, here I will write you again but now, specifically pointing out the problem. Thank you, again!

Comment: I agree with @BenBolker I am a long-term Stata user but have only occasionally used R. Ben is a long-term R user and perhaps has never used Stata but would have enough general programming expertise to guess at what the Stata code is doing. But the question is only trivial for a smaller number of people fluent in both Stata and R and why should they act as a code-writing service? As he says this kind of question isn't really what SO is for; otherwise anyone could ask "I don't have code but need some".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help!!

```
numbers2words <- function(x){
  
  helper <- function(x){
    
    digits <- rev(strsplit(as.character(x), "")[[1]])
    nDigits <- length(digits)
    if (nDigits == 1) as.vector(ones[digits])
    else if (nDigits == 2)
      if (x <= 19) as.vector(teens[digits[1]])
    else trim(paste(tens[digits[2]],
                    Recall(as.numeric(digits[1]))))
    else if (nDigits == 3) trim(paste(ones[digits[3]], "mil", 
                                      Recall(makeNumber(digits[2:1]))))
    else {
      nSuffix <- ((nDigits + 2) %/% 3) - 1
      if (nSuffix > length(suffixes)) stop(paste(x, "is too large!"))
      trim(paste(Recall(makeNumber(digits[
        nDigits:(3*nSuffix + 1)])),
        suffixes[nSuffix],  
        Recall(makeNumber(digits[(3*nSuffix):1]))))
    }
  }
  trim <- function(text){
    gsub("^\ ", "", gsub("\ *$", "", text))
  }  
  makeNumber <- function(...) as.numeric(paste(..., collapse=""))     
  opts <- options(scipen=100) 
  on.exit(options(opts)) 
  ones <- c("", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete",
            "ocho", "nueve") 
  names(ones) <- 0:9 
  teens <- c("diez", "once", "doce", "trece", "catorce", "quince",
             "dieciséis", "dieciséis", "dieciocho", "diecinueve")
  names(teens) <- 0:9 
  tens <- c("veinte", "treinta", "cuarenta", "cincuenta", "sesenta", "setenta", "ochenta",
            "noventa") 
  names(tens) <- 2:9 
  x <- round(x)
  suffixes <- c("mil", "millón", "billón", "trillón")     
  if (length(x) > 1) return(sapply(x, helper))     
  helper(x) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A resource like [Dictionary: Stata to R](https://github.com/EconometricsBySimulation/RStata/wiki/Dictionary:-Stata-to-R) will help you get started.

However, as Ben Bolker suggests, you really just need an R script that converts numbers to Spanish names. The `spanish` package, [available from CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=spanish) is just this. See [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spanish/spanish.pdf) for `to_number` and `to_words`, in particular.